# How to convert a DynamicImage into an ImageBuffer?

Tags: image, types, rust

When I run the following code, the last line results in this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:25:13
   |
25 |     box_filter(&img, 5, 5);
   |                ^^^^ expected struct `ImageBuffer`, found enum `DynamicImage`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&ImageBuffer<Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>>`
              found reference `&DynamicImage`
```

```rust
extern crate image;
extern crate imageproc;

use image::GenericImageView;
use imageproc::filter::box_filter;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // Use the open function to load an image from a Path.
    // `open` returns a `DynamicImage` on success.
    // `unwrap` returns a `panic` when it receives a `None`.
    let img = image::open(
        "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Multiprocessor real-time scheduling/Project2/data/aLIEz.jpg",
    )
    .unwrap();

    // The dimensions method returns the images width and height.
    println!("dimensions {:?}", img.dimensions());

    // The color method returns the image's `ColorType`.
    println!("{:?}", img.color());

    // Write the contents of this image to the Writer in PNG format.
    img.save(
        "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Multiprocessor real-time scheduling/Project2/data_output/test.png",
    )
    .unwrap();

    box_filter(&img, 5, 5);
}
```

I don't know how to convert a `DynamicImage` into an `ImageBuffer` so that I can apply filters. I have seen the documentation of `image 0.23.12` dependency, but I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

- [`image::open().unwrap()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/fn.open.html) results in a [`image::DynamicImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/enum.DynamicImage.html)
- [`imageproc::filter::box_filter()`](https://docs.rs/imageproc/0.22.0/imageproc/filter/fn.box_filter.html) takes a [`image::GrayImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.6/image/type.GrayImage.html)
- To convert a `image::DynamicImage` into a `image::GrayImage` use the
  [`to_luma8()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.to_luma8)
  method

This updated example should work:

```rust
extern crate image;
extern crate imageproc;
use image::GenericImageView;
use imageproc::filter::box_filter;

fn main() {
    let dynamic_image = image::open("path/here").unwrap();
    let gray_image = dynamic_image.to_luma8();
    let result = box_filter(&gray_image, 5, 5);
}
```

If you need an [`image::RgbImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/type.RgbImage.html) or [`image::RgbaImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/type.RgbaImage.html) then call [`into_rgb8()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.into_rgb8) or [`into_rgba8()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.into_rgba8). However `box_filter()` only supports `image::GrayImage`.